# DTale Python Library Error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've installed Dtale (`pip install dtale`) via the terminal in Anaconda, and would like to use it in my Jupyter Notebooks with Pandas.  But when I `import dtale`, I get the following error.  Can anyone suggest what is wrong?  I have numpy installed (`numpy==1.20.2`).

I tried dtale in a collab notebook, and it works nicely.  But not on my local Anaconda.

Thank you!

```
TypeError: <class 'numpy.typing._dtype_like._SupportsDType'> is not a generic class
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Azhar.  Here is an update:  I was able to run Dtale without problem in Google Collab (I started a new NB, then did `!pip install dtale`.   However, when I create a new VENV locally in Anaconda, then import dtale and the dtale app, I get an error:  `Exception on /dtale/iframe/1 [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rfreedma/opt/anaconda3/envs/dtale/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

Comment: Did you activate the env before you installed dtale? Also, activate the env before launching notebook or select correct python in notebook. If possible, first try these without virtual env.